# ORM data modeling in Python Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, orm

I am trying to create a data model in Django, and would like some help from those familiar with Django ORM to advice the right approach to create the data models.

The idea:
I want to store a list of hashtags that are associated in social media posts. 1 post can have multiple hashtags.

**Question 1:**
Is below the right data representation of the model above?

```
Hashtag table:
==============
 - hashtag_id (primary key)
 - hashtag_name

Post table:
============
 - Post_id (primary key)
 - Post_name

Hashtag-post link table:
=========================
 - hashtag_id (link to id in hashtag table, need to specify primary key?)
 - Post_id (link to id in post table)
```

**Question 2:**
How do I create the ORM model with proper primary/foreign keys?

**Question 3:**
How do I make this query: Query all the posts associated in a hashtag in Django ORM?

Comment: Every hashtag should have it's own post, associated with it. It would be better to use Foreign Key in Post -> Hashtag

Comment: Please refer to [this very useful page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) on Django's official website

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Question 1: Is below the right data representation of the model above?

Yes, but you do not need to define the many-to-many table yourself. Django does it for you.

You need to do it in case you want to add attributes to the relationship, in which case you define a 'through-table'. Please [read here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) for more info on that.

- Question 2: How do I create the ORM model with proper primary/foreign keys?

You models could be of this sort:

```
from django.db import models
class Hashtag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.name

class Post(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    hashtags = models.ManyToManyField(Hashtag)

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.name
```

Again: you do not need to define the models' primary keys, Django does it for you (you still can if you need to).

Django adds an `id` field to the model automatically and that is its default primary key (also known as `pk`).

- Question 3: How do I make this query: Query all the posts associated in a hashtag in Django ORM?

In several ways, e.g.:

```
Post.objects.filter(hastags__pk=1)
Post.objects.filter(hastags=1)
Post.objects.filter(hashtags=h1)  # where h1 is an hashtag object instance
Post.objects.filter(hashtags__name__startswith="Science")
```

Please refer to [this very informative and useful page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) on Django's website.

And [this one](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) about making queries that span relationships.